# How to improve this Ruby case switch statement?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering if there's a more elegant way to say this in Ruby:

```
FREE_PLAN_MAXIMUM = 1
BASIC_PLAN_MAXIMUM = 10
PREMIUM_PLAN_MAXIMUM = 100

def maximum_entries_per_month
  case plan
  when "premium"
    PREMIUM_PLAN_MAXIMUM
  when "basic"
    BASIC_PLAN_MAXIMUM
  else
    FREE_PLAN_MAXIMUM
  end 
end
```

I don't like the repetition of `premium` and `basic` inside the function. What might be an alternative?

Comment: What repetition are you seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the rest of your code, especially whether you're using those constants in other places. One pattern I've found nice for this kind of thing is a hash, though.

```
PLAN_MAXIMUMS = { free: 1, basic: 10, premium: 100 }

def maximum_entries_per_month
  PLAN_MAXIMUMS[plan.to_sym] || PLAN_MAXIMUMS[:free]
end
```

Comment: [`PLAN_MAXIMUMS.default = 1`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D) and just `PLAN_MAXIMUMS[plan.to_sym]` would also work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), which allows for a default value, instead of a case statement.

```
PLAN_MAXIMUMS = { free: 1, basic: 10, premium: 100 }

def maximum_entries_per_month
  PLAN_MAXIMUMS.fetch(plan.to_sym, PLAN_MAXIMUMS[:free])
end
```

Comment: +1 I'd never seen fetch before, though I also think my naive " || " is pretty concise and readable

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I am still new to Rails I went with spike's syntax because it's easier for me to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a method. Just have a hash:

```
maximum_entries_per_month = Hash.new(1).merge{"premium" => 100, "basic" => 10}
```

and call:

```
maximum_entries_per_month[plan]
```

Comment: I was about to post the same--just wait 'til I get my new keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
FREE_PLAN_MAXIMUM = 1
BASIC_PLAN_MAXIMUM = 10
PREMIUM_PLAN_MAXIMUM = 100
PLANS = {'premium' => PREMIUM_PLAN_MAXIMUM, 'basic' => BASIC_PLAN_MAXIMUM, 'free' => FREE_PLAN_MAXIMUM}

def maximum_entries_per_month
  PLANS[plan] or FREE_PLAN_MAXIMUM
end
```

that "or FREE_PLAN_MAXIMUM" will catch any plan that's not "premium", "basic" or "free", if you are sure you only have those three plans just remove that part

EDIT: this way you keep your other constants working

EDIT2: if you don't want to add more constants and you are sure plan is one of those, you can do:

```
def maximum_entries_per_month
  self.class.const_get("#{plan.upcase}_PLAN_MAXIMUM")
end
```